# Outside loop to run my program 1000 times and keep a tally - Java

Tags: java, loops

I used to have some basic java skills but it has been a couple of years since I used them. My program does everything I want once, but I need it to run the program 1000 times and keep a total of the `rtCorrect` and `rtIncorrect`. Those 2 totals are actually the only things I will need in the end (i.e. I will only need that last commented out statement). I am not sure if I should just be adding an outside loop in my main method or if I should have a seperate method. I am not worried about it being pretty so I would rather just do it all in the main method with a simple loop.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Thesis {

        public static void main (String [] args){

        int correct = 0;
        int incorrect = 0;
        int rtCorrect = 0;
        int rtIncorrect = 0;


            while(correct<20 && incorrect<20){
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    int pickedNumber = rand.nextInt(100);
                    if (pickedNumber<52){
                        correct++;
                    }
                    else if (pickedNumber>51){
                        incorrect++;
                    }
                    if (correct == 20){
                        rtCorrect = rtCorrect + correct + incorrect;
                    }
                    else if (incorrect == 20){
                        rtIncorrect = rtIncorrect + incorrect + correct;
                    }
                }

        }
        System.out.printf("Correct: %d Incorrect: %d", correct, incorrect);
        System.out.printf ("\nCorrect Response Time: %d\nIncorrect Response Time: %d", rtCorrect, rtIncorrect);
        //System.out.printf ("\nTotal Correct RT's: %d \nTotal Incorrect RT's: %d", totalRTCorrect, totalRTIncorrect);

    }

}
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Thesis {

        public static void main (String [] args){

        int correct = 0;
        int incorrect = 0;
        int rtCorrect = 0;
        int rtIncorrect = 0;


        for (int j = 0; j < 1000;j++){
            int totalRTIncorrect = 0;
            int totalRTCorrect = 0;

            while(correct<20 && incorrect<20){
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    int pickedNumber = rand.nextInt(100);
                    if (pickedNumber<52){
                        correct++;
                    }
                    else if (pickedNumber>52){
                        incorrect++;
                    }
                    if (correct == 20){
                        rtCorrect = rtCorrect + correct + incorrect;
                    }
                    else if (incorrect == 20){
                        rtIncorrect = rtIncorrect + incorrect + correct;
                    }
                }

                totalRTIncorrect = totalRTIncorrect + rtIncorrect;
                totalRTCorrect = totalRTCorrect + rtCorrect;
                System.out.printf ("\nTotal Correct RT's: %d \nTotal Incorrect RT's: %d", totalRTCorrect, totalRTIncorrect);
        }
```

and

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Thesis {

        public static void main (String [] args){

        int correct = 0;
        int incorrect = 0;
        int rtCorrect = 0;
        int rtIncorrect = 0;
        int totalRTIncorrect = 0;
        int totalRTCorrect = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < 1000;j++){

            while(correct<20 && incorrect<20){
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    int pickedNumber = rand.nextInt(100);
                    if (pickedNumber<52){
                        correct++;
                    }
                    else if (pickedNumber>52){
                        incorrect++;
                    }
                    if (correct == 20){
                        rtCorrect = rtCorrect + correct + incorrect;
                    }
                    else if (incorrect == 20){
                        rtIncorrect = rtIncorrect + incorrect + correct;
                    }
                }

                totalRTIncorrect = totalRTIncorrect + rtIncorrect;
                totalRTCorrect = totalRTCorrect + rtCorrect;
        }
        System.out.printf ("\nTotal Correct RT's: %d \nTotal Incorrect RT's: %d", totalRTCorrect, totalRTIncorrect);
        //System.out.printf("Correct: %d Incorrect: %d", correct, incorrect);
        //System.out.printf ("\nCorrect Response Time: %d\nIncorrect Response Time: %d", rtCorrect, rtIncorrect);


    }

}
```

Neither one of these is giving me what I need. The first one just prints out one iteration of the program 1000 times and the second one gives me one of the RT's as 34000 or whatever RT it came to on one iteration x 1000 and the other RT as 0

Comment: Yes, you can call main() in outside loop (by writing another main() method), or you can call the jvm in loop using shell scripts. It's no really matter how to do it for your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either. I would suggest (as you're new to it) just putting a for loop around your code, and when that is working then refactor it out into separate methods if you like.

If you refactor it into a new method I would suggest doing  in your main()

```
 MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
myclass.runProgram();
```

And then have runProgram() do the looping, and another method to the stuff you already have, and keep the current tallys as member variables of MyClass.  Avoiding chaining up a load of static calls and having to have return values.

Ok... this part is to address the comments below:

```
    public static void main (String [] args){


            int totalRTIncorrect = 0;
            int totalRTCorrect = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < 1000;j++){

                int correct = 0;
                int incorrect = 0;
                int rtCorrect = 0;
                int rtIncorrect = 0;

                while(correct<20 && incorrect<20){
                    ...
```

Comment: I tried to just wrap it all in a for loop. I tried 2 different ways of doing this but neither one is giving me the data I need (see edit).

Comment: Look at your rtCorrect and rtIncorrect. Should they be declared inside your outer loop? Otherwise they will get incremented every loop of you  thousand loops, when it looks like you want to start from scratch each loop.

Comment: I could be wrong, because  don't know why you need to do it 1000 times, but in your original code you initialised all your variables to 0 and then do the while loop. Now you introduced an outer for loop, but your variables only get initialised to 0 once. Perhaps you only need the totals outside the for loop, and the rest inside the for loop where they used to be.

Comment: What I need is for it to do exactly what the first code does first. That code runs until correct or incorrect gets to 20 and then shows how many numbers were generated before that happened. If incorrect reached 20 first and 35 numbers were generated before that happened than "rtIncorrect" is 35. IF the next trial rtIncorrect is 30 than I want totalRTIncorrect to now be 65. What I need is for that process to run 1000 times and keep a total tally of the values of rtIncorrect and rtCorrect and give me the totals for each after 1000 trials.

Comment: Ok. Try moving all of you int declarations (except the totals) inside the outer for loop. Does that work any better? I'll add example to my answer to be clear...

Comment: That final suggestion worked perfectly, I knew it had to something to do with where I was declaring/initializing variables but I couldn't quite figure it out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2916352 Make sure you take the time to understand why this made a difference : )

Answer (score 0):

In this case, because you know how often you want the code to loop, you use a `for loop`. The syntax is as follows:

```
for(counter; termination condition; incremental step)
```

So for example:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 1000; x++)
```

In the context of your code, you just wrap this around your method as follows:

```
for(int x =0; x < 1000; x++) {

 while(correct<20 && incorrect<20){
                Random rand = new Random();
                int pickedNumber = rand.nextInt(100);
                if (pickedNumber<52){
                    correct++;
                }
                else if (pickedNumber>51){
                    incorrect++;
                }
                if (correct == 20){
                    rtCorrect = rtCorrect + correct + incorrect;
                }
                else if (incorrect == 20){
                    rtIncorrect = rtIncorrect + incorrect + correct;
                }
   }
}
```

Then when the code is finished, print out your values and you'll have your sampling data for `1000` cases, although on a more scientific note, if you're writing this for a thesis and you're dealing with a PRNG (Pseudo-random number generator) then you want a much, much larger sampling frame than that. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help. I have gotten as far as wrapping my method in a for loop but am unable to get it to give me the info I need. My problem is if I initialize the new variable I want (totalRtCorrect and totalRTIncorrect) inside the for loop and then try to just print out the totals one time outside the for loop than they reinitialize to 0 every time and if I move the statement to print them out into the for loop then it just prints out one RT 1000 times. I will try to post my two code versions to clarify